# Export data to excel using Data from Gridview Yii2

Tags: yii2

hi all i faced problems here

after i find a way to retrieve id data from gridview, now my problem is export the data to excel. here is my code in controller

```
public function actionCetakdispo()
{

$selection=(array)Yii::$app->request->post('selection');    
$template = \Yii::getAlias("@webroot") . "/template/dispo.xlsx";
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($template);
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();//typecasting
foreach($selection as $id){
    $suratmasuks = Smwp::findOne((int)$id);        
    $baserow = 5;
    $no = 1;
    foreach($suratmasuks as $suratmasuk){
        $row = $no + $baserow;
        $worksheet->getCell('A'. $row)->setValue($no);
        $worksheet->getCell('B'. $row)->setValue($suratmasuk->jenis_surat);
        $worksheet->getCell('C'. $row)->setValue($suratmasuk->perihal);
        $no++;
    }

}
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="dispo.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'berhasil download!');
$writer->save('php://output');      
exit;
}
```

its show an error : Trying to get property 'jenis_surat' of non-object. if i print_r($surat_masuks), its show like this :

```
app\models\SmWp Object (
  [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array (
    [id] => 4
    [id_mfwp] => 1
    [id_user] => 3
    [tgl_surat] => 2019-10-08 00:00:00
    [tgl_terima] => 2019-10-15 00:00:00
    [tgl_cetak] => 2019-10-14 00:00:00
    [nomor_surat] => kksksk
    [no_agenda] => 992929
    [jenis_surat] => 3
    [perihal] => balasan surat kami
    [lokasi_scan] => 
    [ket_dispo] => kerjakan
    [index_cetak_dispo] => 0
    [index_cetak_reg] => 0
  )
  [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array (
    [id] => 4
    [id_mfwp] => 1
    [id_user] => 3
    [tgl_surat] => 2019-10-08 00:00:00
    [tgl_terima] => 2019-10-15 00:00:00
    [tgl_cetak] => 2019-10-14 00:00:00
    [nomor_surat] => kksksk
    [no_agenda] => 992929
    [jenis_surat] => 3
    [perihal] => balasan surat kami
    [lokasi_scan] => 
    [ket_dispo] => kerjakan
    [index_cetak_dispo] => 0
    [index_cetak_reg] => 0
  )
  [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( ) 
  [_relationsDependencies:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( ) 
  [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
  [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
  [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default 
  [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) 
  [_eventWildcards:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) 
  [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( )
)
```

thx for explanation..

Edit : this is my gridview code

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,

    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',],
        'id',
        'kategori',
        'nama_wp',
        'nama',             
        'nomor_surat', 
        'tgl_surat',
        'perihal',
        'ket',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 'checkboxOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
            return ['value' => $model['id'] ];
         },],
    ],
    ]); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `findOne` will always return only one instance of Smwp model. Not an array of multiple models.

```php
$suratmasuks = Smwp::findOne((int)$id);
```

Because `\yii\db\ActiveRecord` implements `IteratorAgregate` interface ([see documentation](https://www.php.net/class.iteratoraggregate)) you can use it in foreach like this:

```php
foreach ($suratmasuks as $suratmasuk) {
    // ...
}
```

But in $suratmasuk won't be instances of `Smwp` but values of attributes of that one instance loaded by `findOne`.

You can load all models with following find and get rid of outer foreach.

```php
$suratmasuks = Smwp::find()
    ->where(['id' => $selection])
    ->all();
```

Your whole code can look like

```php
public function actionCetakdispo()
{
    $selection=(array)Yii::$app->request->post('selection');    
    $template = \Yii::getAlias("@webroot") . "/template/dispo.xlsx";
    $spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($template);
    $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();//typecasting

    $suratmasuks = Smwp::find()
        ->where(['id' => $selection])
        ->all();        
    $baserow = 5;
    $no = 1;
    foreach($suratmasuks as $suratmasuk){
        $row = $no + $baserow;
        $worksheet->getCell('A'. $row)->setValue($no);
        $worksheet->getCell('B'. $row)->setValue($suratmasuk->jenis_surat);
        $worksheet->getCell('C'. $row)->setValue($suratmasuk->perihal);
        $no++;
    }
    $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="dispo.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'berhasil download!');
    $writer->save('php://output');      
    exit;
}
```

If you wanted to keep loading the model by one you should get rid of the inner foreach instead and output it like this:

```php
$baserow = 5;
$no = 1;
foreach($selection as $id){
    $suratmasuks = Smwp::findOne((int)$id);            
    $row = $no + $baserow;
    $worksheet->getCell('A'. $row)->setValue($no);
    $worksheet->getCell('B'. $row)->setValue($suratmasuks->jenis_surat);
    $worksheet->getCell('C'. $row)->setValue($suratmasuks->perihal);
    $no++;
}
```

But this will mean your script will do much more queries to DB so the first way is better.

Comment: thx for respons..i want to export data from gridview that i choose with check box.i retrieve the id and looping it using find one

Comment: hi my friend, code works but only 1 row selected eventhough i select more than 1 row in gridview checkbox..you can read my view code, is that any mistakes there?

Comment: Can you print_r the value of `$selection` variable?

Comment: voila.. i have miss typed.. i write  $baserow = 5; $no = 1; inside the foreach looping.. i edit it and put it just before foreach looping..and works so good..thx my friend..